R data.table select specific column by column name among multiple columns with the same name
Trying to select a specific DT column by column name, but the DT has several columns with the same name:
DT = data.table(a=1:3, a=4:6, a=7:9, b=10:12, a=13:15)

> DT
   a a a  b  a
1: 1 4 7 10 13
2: 2 5 8 11 14
3: 3 6 9 12 15

DT colnames are the same:
> colnames(DT)
[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "a"

But viewing DT "colnames" are different:
View(DT)


How can i select the "a.2" column by it's name?

I don't know why you would want to work with repeated column names (seems like a terrible idea). But you could:
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = names(DT) == "a" & rowid(names(DT)) == 3L]

#        a
#    <int>
# 1:     7
# 2:     8
# 3:     9

You could also just fix the names as seems to happen with View() in Rstudio:
setnames(DT, make.unique(names(DT)))

#        a   a.1   a.2     b   a.3
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     4     7    10    13
# 2:     2     5     8    11    14
# 3:     3     6     9    12    15

# setnames(DT, paste(names(DT), rowid(names(DT))-1, sep = "_"))

#      a_0   a_1   a_2   b_0   a_3
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     4     7    10    13
# 2:     2     5     8    11    14
# 3:     3     6     9    12    15


have to analyse a large dataset with some columns with the same names. In your solution you are using the columns position. That way it would be simpler to select column by it index: DT[,3]. What i'm trying to do is to select column by its name. In the example, want to select the thirth column with the name "a", or call the "a.2" position by its name.
Thanks anyway

the problem is that there is no a.2 in your example it's all a... but you could fix that (see updated answer)

Thats it! '''setnames(DT, make.unique(names(DT)))''' solve it. When rowbinding csv by '''rbindlist (lapply(files, fread...''' it generates a DT that doesnt individualize column names when they are the same. A very different behaviour of '''lapply(files,fread...)''' But rbindlist is so much faster, i was definitely looking for a way to get it done. Thanks!
